# Distant speech generator

Tags: signals, distance, speech

Can anyone suggest me a distant speech generator tool? Ideally, I want to provide a clean speech sample and a distance (like 1m, 2m, 3m ...) to the tool, and the tool will generate the distant speech version of that original speech. Any programmable/non-programmable tool is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple generation is available in sox with [reverb](https://linux.die.net/man/1/soxexam) tool

```
sox file.orig.wav file.wav reverb 1.0 600.0 180.0 200.0 220.0 240.0 280.0 300.0
```

Advanced Matlab implementation is [here](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/20962-image-source-method-for-room-impulse-response-simulation--room-acoustics-)